# Bootstrap 3 Panel Layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello I have some panels I'd like to be on the left side of my page, at the moment I can't get them all equal and to the left side.

How would I do this?

Here is My code so far:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One|Raleway:100,200,400,600,700,900,500,800,300|Roboto+Condensed:400,700,400italic,700italic,300italic,300);

/*!
Custom CSS || Created By ______ @________

 Global Styles
============================================================ */
html { 

    -webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
    -moz-background-size: 100% auto;
    -o-background-size: 100% auto;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}

body {
    padding-top: 50px; 
    font-family: 'poiret One', 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    background-color: transparent;
} 

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
    font-family: 'Raleway', 'poiret One', 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    color: #000;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Raleway', 'poiret One', 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    color: #000;
}

.About-Us {
    padding-top: 100px;
}

.menu-product {
    height: 160px;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu-link {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 240px;
    width: 240px;
    border: 1px solid #0095D5;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    background-size: cover !important;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-link:hover {
    transform: scale(1.025);
}

.menu-link > span {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background: #0095D5;
    color: white;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<!-- Title  
===================================================================================-->
        <title>Cold Cure Windows</title>

        <!-- CSS Stylesheets  
===================================================================================-->
        <link href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
        <link href = "css/custom.css" rel = "stylesheet">
        <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/bocFav.png">
        
<!-- Custom Fonts 
===================================================================================-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>

<body>

<!-- Abouts Us
==================================================================================-->
    <section id="About-Us" class="About-Us">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 vline">
                    <h3>About Us</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium veniam exercitationem expedita laborum at voluptate. Labore, voluptates totam at aut nemo deserunt rem magni pariatur quos perspiciatis atque eveniet unde.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium veniam exercitationem expedita laborum at voluptate. Labore, voluptates totam at aut nemo deserunt rem magni pariatur quos perspiciatis atque eveniet unde.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium veniam exercitationem expedita laborum at voluptate. Labore, voluptates totam at aut nemo deserunt rem magni pariatur quos perspiciatis atque eveniet unde.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium veniam exercitationem expedita laborum at voluptate. Labore, voluptates totam at aut nemo deserunt rem magni pariatur quos perspiciatis atque eveniet unde.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium veniam exercitationem expedita laborum at voluptate. Labore, voluptates totam at aut nemo deserunt rem magni pariatur quos perspiciatis atque eveniet unde.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium veniam exercitationem expedita laborum at voluptate. Labore, voluptates totam at aut nemo deserunt rem magni pariatur quos perspiciatis atque eveniet unde.</p>
                </div>
                    <div class="container menu-product">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="menu col-lg-1">
                                <a href="#" class="menu-link" style="background: url('/img/Image1.jpg');">
                                    <span>Windows</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="menu col-lg-1">
                                <a href="#" class="menu-link" style="background: url('/img/Image1.jpg');">
                                    <span>Windows</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="menu col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-6">
                                <a href="#" class="menu-link" style="background: url('/img/Image1.jpg');">
                                    <span>Windows</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="menu col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-2">
                                <a href="#" class="menu-link" style="background: url('/img/Image1.jpg');">
                                    <span>Windows</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="menu col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-6">
                                <a href="#" class="menu-link" style="background: url('/img/Image1.jpg');">
                                    <span>Windows</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="menu col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-6">
                                <a href="#" class="menu-link" style="background: url('/img/Image1.jpg');">
                                    <span>Windows</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help is appreciated thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a lot of code here. Please edit your question to keep only the relevant code.

Comment: @GustavoStraube done